# Why might a free woman have a child with a slave?

Tags: relationship-analysis

Below is is a baptism record for a child Samuel in the Virgin Islands. The columns are for parents' names, then occupation, then civil status, then day baptized and then where they live. Eve is free but "Andrew Donavan" is a slave. The date is 1826.

I've heard of this being the case the other way round, slave owning men having their way with their coloured slaves, but I'm researching my Potter ancestors, and this record lists an Eve Potter, free, having a child with a man who is a slave (S for slave on the register).

I don't know if Eve Potter was a free coloured woman or white, but this seems strange to me. What might the circumstances surrounding this relationship have been?

[image]

Comment: What are the headings on those columns?  Have you found a baptism record for Eve?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say. To clarify, this is a baptism record for the child Samuel. Next column is parents' names, then occupation, then civil status, then day baptized and then where they live. Eve is free but "Andrew Donavan" is a slave.

Comment: Please use the edit button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications

Comment: Does A.free stand for African free?

Comment: What date is the record?

Comment: 1826, British Virgin Islands

Comment: Sometimes the status slave does not mean to be one, even more likely due to this record being made in the 19th century. I could well be in this particular case that legally speaking  the woman (free) bought the men (slave) because they fell in love, she married him and was able to free him legally (afterwards). I know of a case like (around the same time) this in the US, although there the partner was freed before the marriage. If something like this could be possible you should check any slave records to clarify.

Comment: Parking this here for reference: https://hydra.hull.ac.uk/assets/hull:5764a/content Has reference to a slave married to a free woman, who later bought his freedom.

Comment: Thank you, ColeValleyGirl, for referencing. Now, it is even the more credible.

Comment: @Charlie- If you look carefully at the 5th column, you'll see that there is a 'ditto' mark (") in the row for Eve, directly below the "B" for 'Andrew'. This seems to indicate that Eve was also a black person.

Comment: @TilHund is correct, there is precedent for free people of color buying enslaved people in order to protect them and to keep families intact. Another thing to consider is that the status follow matrilineal lines, that is, children born to enslaved women were also enslaved. A child born to a free woman of color would be free.